# ClickHouse view - AggregateFunction column vs usual column

Tags: sql, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I have declared my aggregation table as:

```
CREATE TABLE test.system_aggr
(
         system_id String,

         aggr_val AggregateFunction(sum, Int64)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (system_id);
```

correspondingly my mat.view is:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.system_aggr_mv
TO test.system_aggr
AS
SELECT
    
    system_id,

    sumState(raw_val) as aggr_val

FROM test.system_base
GROUP BY
    system_id;
```

now my question is, what's the advantage of using `AggregateFunction(...)`, instead of just declaring `aggr_val` as `Int64` and using `sum(...)` in materialized view? see below:

```
CREATE TABLE test.system_aggr
(
         system_id String,

         aggr_val Int64
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (system_id);
```

and

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.system_aggr_mv
TO test.system_aggr
AS
SELECT
    
    system_id,

    sum(raw_val) as aggr_val

FROM test.system_base
GROUP BY
    system_id;
```

---

UPD. One thing that I noticed is that I need to use `GROUP BY` while selecting from aggregation table in case if it has at least one column of type `AggregateFunction`, so all columns that are not `AggregateFunction` should be in `GROUP BY`. This further makes me doubt about usefulness of having `AggregateFunction` columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer by myself,
seems that the values don't get aggregated properly if usual aggregation functions are used instead of `<function_name>State(...)` in mat.views (and correspondingly `AggregateFunction` in aggregation tables)

For example, if I insert 4, 5, 6 sequentially (i.e. with three separate inserts) into base table, and then run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` over aggregation table, I see only 4, instead of expected 15

Answer (score 0):

> what's the advantage of using AggregateFunction(...), instead of just declaring aggr_val as Int64 and using sum(...) in materialized view?

This isn't quite the way to ask that question. It's not an "advantage" to use `AggregateFunction`, it's a requirement. The only time you can avoid `AggregateFunction` data types is in `SummingMergeTree` - which is a convenience in that table engine where numeric columns are summed together for you.

Check out a detailed explanation here of why `AggregateFunction` is needed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ma2ohy_6lM

Comment: that's not true. I am currently using the aggregation table without `AggregateFunction` data types AND having `AggregatingMergeTree`